# How to update existing rows based in next month on current month data in same SQL table?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have one SQL table called Employee_invoice

| JobSite | Name | InvocieDate | InvoiceAmount | Crew_size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J003297 | David | 3/1/2022 | 1600 | 10 |
| J003297 | Jhon | 5/1/2022 | 2000 | 20 |
| J102899 | Andy | 12/1/2022 | 4000 | 30 |
| J003297 | Olive | 22/1/2022 | 2000 | 45 |
| J003297 | David | 3/2/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| J003297 | Jhon | 5/2/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| J102899 | Andy | 12/2/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| J003297 | Olive | 22/2/2022 | 0 | 0 |

So I want to update InvoiceAmount, Crew_size column of next month i.e. February based Previous month i.e. January month. The join condition will be matched on JobSite and Name column.

I want a stored procedure for this, which will run 1st day of every month and update multiple columns. (@Tabletype)

The result table should look like this:
[image]

Comment: can you share the DBMS you're using and your latest coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I am using SQL Server. I have created a table type to pass as a parameter.@lemon